# Generically surjective morphism of vector bundles. How to get them?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be vector bundles on a smooth projective scheme $X$. Let $\varphi : \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of vector bundles with ranks $m$ and $n$, respectively, and $m > n$.

The set $$D_{k}(\varphi) = \bigl \{ x \in X ; \text{rank}(\varphi(x))\leq k \bigr \}$$ where $k \leq \text{min}\bigl \{ m, n \bigr \}$ is called degeneracy locus of rank $k$ of $\varphi$.

Suppose that $\varphi_{x} : \mathcal{F}_{x} \longrightarrow \mathcal{G}_{x}$ is not surjective for all $x \in X$. Let $U$ be a dense open subset of $X$.

To show that $\varphi$ is generically surjective, we must show that $\varphi_{p} : \mathcal{F}_{p} \longrightarrow \mathcal{G}_{p}$ is surjective for all $p \in U$. Right or wrong? Does information about the $D_{k}(\varphi)$ set allow us to show this? What is the best strategy to show that such morphism is generically surjective?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: I believe that you are missing that for $m>n$, $\phi_x$ is surjective if and only if it has maximal rank hence you only want $D_n(\varphi)$ not to be the whole $X$.

Comment: Hi, Alan Muniz. That is, I have to show that $D_{n}(\varphi) = U$.

Comment: I was confused with the notation. In fact you must show that $D_{n-1}(\varphi)\neq X$

Comment: Hi, Alan Muniz. That is, I have to show that $D_{n}(\varphi) = U$. Think about blowing up $\pi$ of $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ along a irreducible smooth curve $C$ with exceptional divisor $E$. In $$ U = \widetilde{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \setminus (E \cup  \bigl \{ p_{1}, \cdots, p_{n} \bigr \})$$ the morphism $$\varphi : \pi^{*}(T_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}) \longrightarrow  \mathcal{L} = N_{\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}}$$ is generically surjective?

Comment: $\mathcal{L} = N_{\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}}$ is a line bundle. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Outside $E$ the blow up is an isomorphism. If you know that on $\mathbb{P}3$ this holds...

Comment: Outside E the blow up is an isomorphism.  Yes, I know. Does this imply that such morphism is surjective in $ U $?

Comment: I believe you should write everything locally and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104286/discussion-between-allan-ramos-and-alan-muniz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V\subset X$ be a small open subset where both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are trivial.  After choosing trivializations $\varphi|_V \in {\rm Hom}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})|_V$ is given by  a $n \times m$ matrix $A_V$ with entries in $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$. Hence for every $x\in V$,
$$
{\rm rk}\ \varphi_x = {\rm rk}\ A_V(x) 
$$
In particular, it can be computed using the minors of $A_V(x)$. Indeed $D_{k-1}(\varphi) \cap V$ (in your notation) is given by the vanishing of the  $k\times k$ minors of $A_V$.

We now arrive at the following equivalence: $\varphi$ is generically surjective if and only if $D_{n-1}(\varphi) \neq X$. Indeed $\varphi_x$ is surjective if and only if ${\rm rk}\ \varphi_x = n$ if and only if $x \in X \setminus D_{n-1}(\varphi)$. On the other hand $D_{n-1}(\varphi)$ is a closed subvariety of $X$.

Comment: $\varphi|_{U} = \varphi|_{V}$ (in your notation).

Comment: just corrected that

Comment: Dear Alan Muniz. In my case, my set that I'm calling $ U $ is actually $X \setminus D_{n-1}(\varphi)$?

Comment: At least $U\subset X \setminus D_{n-1}(\varphi)$

Comment: Truth. The last question : Is it always possible to get such an open subset $ V $?

Comment: Always. Once you have open subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$ where each vector bundle has a trivialization, just take $V= V_1 \cap V_2$

Comment: Dear Alan Muniz. Once again, thank you very much for your reply. Success !

Comment: Where can I learn more about morphisms between vector bundles? Can someone give me a good reference? Thank you.

Comment: @Emanuell I believe Shafarevich's basic algebraic geometry (vol 2) is a good source for the basic definitions from which you can work out other properties or read more advanced references. For a complex analytic geometry I'd suggest Huybrecht's book, Griffiths & Harris or Demailly's

Comment: Thank you very much @AlanMuniz.